# How can I use Play/Activator to publish to github?

Tags: github, playframework-2.0, repository, sbt, typesafe-activator

Try to following Manning's Play for Scala, I've created a git repository at:

https://github.com/nilvon9wo/Ean2BarcodePlayModule

The site is published at:

http://nilvon9wo.github.io/Ean2BarcodePlayModule

In my build.sbt, I've added:

```
organization := "net.nowhereatall.playforscala"

publishTo := Some("Ean2BarcodePlayModule" at "http://nilvon9wo.github.io/Ean2BarcodePlayModule")

credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".repo-credentials" / "credentials.properties")
```

and my credentials.properties is like this:

```
realm="Ean2BarcodePlayModule"
host=http://nilvon9wo.github.io/Ean2BarcodePlayModule
user=xxxxxxxxxxx
password=xxxxxxxxxx
```

When I execute activator publish, it terminates with the following exception:

```
    java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL http://nilvon9wo.github.io/Ean2Barcode
PlayModule/net/nowhereatall/playforscala/ean2barcodeplaymodule_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT
/ean2barcodeplaymodule_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom failed with status code 405: Not Al
lowed
        at org.apache.ivy.util.url.AbstractURLHandler.validatePutStatusCode(Abst
ractURLHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.url.BasicURLHandler.upload(BasicURLHandler.java:2
64)
        at org.apache.ivy.util.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:150)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.url.URLRepository.put(URLRepository
.java:84)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepo
sitory.java:130)
        at sbt.ConvertResolver$ChecksumFriendlyURLResolver$class.put(ConvertReso
lver.scala:80)
        at sbt.ConvertResolver$PluginCapableResolver$1.put(ConvertResolver.scala
:106)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(Repository
Resolver.java:216)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$3.apply(IvyActions.scala:263)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$3.apply(IvyActions.scala:262)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(
TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.
scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.s
cala:771)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:262)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(IvyAc
tions.scala:97)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IvyActions.s
cala:97)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(IvyActions.s
cala:97)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:106)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$withChecksums(IvyActions.scala:101)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:97)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$publish$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:91)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRet
ries$1(Locks.scala:81)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:
102)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.publish(IvyActions.scala:91)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$publishTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1173)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$publishTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1172)
        at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:35)
        at scala.Function3$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function3.scala:34)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric
tions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:publish) java.io.IOException: PUT operation to URL http://nilvon9wo.g
ithub.io/Ean2BarcodePlayModule/net/nowhereatall/playforscala/ean2barcodeplaymodu
le_2.11/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ean2barcodeplaymodule_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom failed with sta
tus code 405: Not Allowed
```

How is the correct way to configure either build.sbt and/or credentials.properties so that `activator publish` will succeed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how relevant this still is, but judging from the repo you linked, you haven't added anything yet, so I'm going to assume it is.

As far as I'm aware, `publish` is only used for publishing the distribution to lets say a fileserver, but not a vcs repository. In order to do that you have to add the files via git instead.

EDIT: As a small addition (because you especially declare it 'site'), I don't think you can deploy a jvm application to run as a github page. Github pages only serve static files, so you might want to look at a PaaS solution if that was the initial plan.

Comment: Cheers for the response.  Was only going through the process to educate myself (as a tactile learner).  My interpretation of the book suggested it should have been possible to use publish, but ultimately that isn't too important right now.